# Struts JSON Plug-In doesn't work with Dependency Injection (Spring)

Tags: json, spring, dependency-injection, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I'm coding a Webapp using Struts 2, Struts 2 JSON Plug-In and Spring(for Dependency Injection).

My Problem is that I want to call this Struts Action

```
@Action(value = "preview", results = {
        @Result(name = "success", type = "json", params = { "root", "emailPreviewBean" }),
        @Result(name = "login", location = "/WEB-INF/content/index.jsp") })
public String preview() {
    emailPreviewBean.setPreviewContent();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

via AJAX

```
function getCurrentPreview() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'preview.action',         
        data : {},
        success : function(result) {
            $('#previewMessage').val(result.previewMessage);
            $('#previewMessage2').val(result.previewMessage2);
            $('#previewSubject').val(result.emailBean.subject);
            $('#previewSubject2').val(result.emailBean.subject2);
        },
    });
}
```

But i get this error message instead of proper JSON:

```
<h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /ZertV/preview.action. Reason:
<pre>    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException</pre>
</p>

Caused by:
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:269)
at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:110)
at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:194)
at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:222)
at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:196)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:366)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:270)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:252)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:260)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:69)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:188)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:120)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:99)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:139)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:155)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:174)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:130)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at de.dataport.ls53.zertv.misc.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:28)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:556)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:113)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Caused by: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:269)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:428)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:254)
    ... 76 more

Caused by: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:269)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:428)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:254)
    ... 81 more

...
....
.....



  <h3>Caused by:</h3>
    <pre>java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:428)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:254)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:428)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:254)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:110)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:194)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:222)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:196)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:366)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:270)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:260)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:69)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:188)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:120)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:155)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:174)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at de.dataport.ls53.zertv.misc.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:28)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:556)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\ZertV\build\tmp\jettyRunWar\webapp (Zugriff verweigert)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.&lt;init&gt;(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.mortbay.resource.FileResource.getInputStream(FileResource.java:275)
    ... 111 more
</pre>
    <h3>Caused by:</h3>
    <pre>java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\ZertV\build\tmp\jettyRunWar\webapp (Zugriff verweigert)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.&lt;init&gt;(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.mortbay.resource.FileResource.getInputStream(FileResource.java:275)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:428)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:254)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:428)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:254)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:428)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:254)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:428)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:254)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:428)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:254)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:428)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:254)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:110)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:194)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:222)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:196)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:366)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:270)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:260)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:69)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:188)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:120)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:155)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:174)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:97)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at de.dataport.ls53.zertv.misc.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:28)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:556)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

This is my `ApplicationContext` for the `emailPreviewBean`:

```
bean id="emailPreviewBean" class="de.dataport.ls53.zertv.beans.EmailPreviewBean" scope="request"> 
     <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\ZertV\build\tmp\jettyRunWar\webapp (Zugriff verweigert)` ??

Comment: Since translating `Zugriff verweigert` gives me `Access Denied`, I guess it's some kind of writing policy problem. Check your Jetty installation.

Comment: The strange thing is when I change `params = { "root", "emailPreviewBean" }`to `params = { "root", "emailPreviewBean.previewMessage" }` (previewMessage is a String) i get this String as JSON, if it were a writing policy problem this should not work.

Comment: Post `emailPreviewBean`. Is it `Serializable` ? Does it have a default constructor ?

Comment: Yes it implemts Serilizable and has a default constructor. Before I set the scope to session everything worked fine.

Comment: Your scope is request, not session. And I've not used spring scopes a lot, apart from singleton and prototype, so I'm not soure about it. But if it is causing the problem, then just revert back to the previous scope

Comment: The Problem is i need it to be request or at least session.

Comment: Why do you want to serialize a spring bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Struts-JSON-Plugin traverses all getters of supplied object to create response. Your supplied object is a request-scope Spring bean! Such object has other Spring-Supplied getters at runtime which you cannot see! Some how it's not a good practice to create json from such complex object!

Struts-JSON-Plugin can not and does not guarantee that no exception occurs when it calls your supplied object's getters. So just use a simpler object to create json from. I mean an object which exactly has your required data, not less, not more.

Another solution is unwrapping Spring proxy from object then use it as `root` for Struts-JSON-Plugin